# How to fix this Wordpress Logo Position

Tags: css

How can I position My site title to the center of the page? I have tried this:

```
#site-title{
    display:inline-block!important;
    max-width:74%;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but no hope. so How can I move my logo to the center?
http://worldsocialnetworking.com/

Answer (score 1):

To set your logo center put `text-align: center;` in this line in your CSS:

```
#top {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; // Add this for center the Logo
}
```

Comment: The simplest way: Remove the `#site-description {}` for this